# Reusing same key with JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a Class EntityA that contains a List of EntityB.

```
@Entity
public class EntityA {
    @Id
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entityAId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    public final List<EntityB> listOfB = new ArrayList<>();

    ...
}

@Entity
public class EntityB {
    @Id
    private long entityAId;

    @Id
    private String name;

    private String value;
    ...
}
```

What I want to do is:

```
EntityA myEntityA = entityManager.find(EntityA.class, 1);
// myEntityA.listOfB contains one element [entityAId = 1, name = "foo", value = "bar"]
myEntityA.listOfB.clear();
myEntityA.listOfB.add(new EntityB(1, "foo", "baz");
entityManager.persist(myEntityA);
// commit transaction here
```

But I get "javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session"
Adding an additional unique ID-field in EntityB "fixes" the problem, but I don't want an additional column in my db. Is there a better way?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this?

Comment: If you want to ignore a UNIQUE constraint then fix your UNIQUE constraint, by changing or removing it. Design classes to model what they are used for ...

Comment: EntityB contains Key-Value Pairs. Only one EntityB with the same Id and Name and exist in the db at a time. I want to be able to delete an EntityB and later be able to reuse it (without persisting in between).

Comment: You won't be able to, because AFAIK, you're not responsible for Hibernate's execution pile. Sometimes it will insert the new entity before deleting the old one, throwing this kind of exception. If you really *can't* use the same object over again, it's gonna be tough. And even if you detach it and reattach later, I'm not sure it'll work. (worth a try?)

Comment: In your execution, after the "clear" the existing B is still in the L1 cache (and possibly L2 cache). You'd have to FLUSH, and then evict those as well to stand any chance of creating a NEW object with the same PK as an earlier deleted object, or you could just UPDATE the existing one!

Comment: I cannot update because I don't know if I will reuse it. The code example only highlights the problem case. Any number of add, remove, and clear (and even updates on EntityB) operations my happen instead of "myEntityA.listOfB.clear(); myEntityA.listOfB.add(new EntityB(1, "foo", "baz");"

Comment: BTW `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "entityAId")` implies that `EntityB.entityAId` is of type `EntityA`, not `long`